# Change Marquee Content Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Before anyone says, I know there are better ways than using a marquee, however, for this instance I am using one.

Depending on the date, I want the marquee to say a different thing. Why is the marquee not changing and always saying default?

**Javascript**

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();

if (n > 0 && n < 8){
 var bday ="Birthday Kids name and age 1"
 }else if(n > 7 && n < 15){
  var bday ="Birthday Kids name and age 2"
 }else if(n > 14 && n < 22){
  var bday ="Birthday Kids name and age 3"
 }else if(n > 21 && n < 29){
  var bday ="Birthday Kids name and age 4"
 }else if(n > 28 && n < 32){
  var bday ="BirthdayKids name and age 5"
 }
 
document.getElementById("birthdays").textContent = "We wish a very happy birthday to "+bday;
```

```html
<marquee bgcolor="#088A08" id="birthdays" direction="left" loop="20" width="100%">Default</marquee>
```

Comment: What's the question? Your code doesnt work btw cuz you used double `=`

Comment: I know how, but since you're trolling the internet with a marquee....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/4L279dk6/)

**Javascript**

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();
if (n > 0 && n < 8){
    var bday ="Birthday Kids name and age 1";
    }else if(n > 7 && n < 15){
        var bday ="Birthday Kids name and age 2";
    }else if(n > 14 && n < 22){
        var bday ="Birthday Kids name and age 3";
    }else if(n > 21 && n < 29){
        var bday ="Birthday Kids name and age 4";
    }else if(n > 28 && n < 32){
        var bday ="BirthdayKids name and age 5";
    }

document.getElementById("birthdays").textContent ="We wish a very happy birthday to "+bday;
```

Notice that i've removed the `==` from your code which solves the problem as there is a problem with the syntax error.

`==` is used for comparisons and for assignments just `=` is used..

Comment: Was it just that causing the problem?

Comment: This works on the fiddle but not on my site, do you have any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: to debug, just put an alert, for eg `alert('working');` before `var d = new Date();` and check if the alert shows.

Comment: Cheers for your help, fixed, was a stupid mistake, placed js in header which caused it not to work, fixed now:)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 document.getElementById("birthdays").innerHTML
```

edit:
replace == with = and make sure the getElementById is called after the element or after the page is loaded